# How to mock return values of a mocked result?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Hi I'm trying to unit test library that pulls data from MongoDB, and using mongo driver for C#.

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
var cursor = _collection.FindAs<DictionaryDocument>(Query.Exists(key)).SetFields(Fields.Include(key)).SetLimit(1);
```

I can successfully test the first part, FindAs here's the simple test snippet:

```
    var collection = GetMockedSettingsCollection();

    collection.Setup(c => c.FindAs<DictionaryDocument>(It.IsAny<IMongoQuery>())).Returns<IMongoQuery>(s => It.IsAny<MongoCursor<DictionaryDocument>>());

    var repo = new MongoSettingsRepository(new MongoStorageConfiguration<DictionaryDocument> {Collection = collection.Object});
```

The problem is I don't know how to mock return value for the code so I can setup for `SetFields` and `SetLimit` afterwards.

Any tips?

**EDIT:**
I've tried to "chain mock" results like this:

```
var collection = GetMockedSettingsCollection();
var mockedFieldsCursor = new Mock<MongoCursor<DictionaryDocument>>();
var mockedLimitCursor = new Mock<MongoCursor<DictionaryDocument>>();

mockedLimitCursor.Setup(c => c.SetLimit(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns<IMongoQuery>(s => It.IsAny<MongoCursor<DictionaryDocument>>());
mockedFieldsCursor.Setup(c => c.SetFields(It.IsAny<IMongoFields>())).Returns<IMongoQuery>(s => mockedLimitCursor.Object);

collection.Setup(c => c.FindAs<DictionaryDocument>(It.IsAny<IMongoQuery>())).Returns<IMongoQuery>(s => mockedFieldsCursor.Object);

var repo = new MongoSettingsRepository(new MongoStorageConfiguration<DictionaryDocument> {Collection = collection.Object});
```

But I'm getting error that Moq cannot instantiate `mockedFieldsCursor.Object`

Comment: IMongoQuery will be mockable, so create a Mock for this, set it up and return the mock.Object from your Returns statement.

Comment: Yes, I've tried something like that, let me post the code.

Comment: What type does `FindAs()` return?  It looks like you're setting it up to return an `IMongoQuery` but using `mockedFieldsCursor.Object`, which isn't the right type (`MongoCursor` doesn't implement `IMongoQuery`).